# SQL Longest Stay

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i would like to ask your help about a problem i got.I got a database of a hotel and i would like to find the costumer with the longest stay.

I got 3 tables:

1. **costumer** (code_costumer,name,surname),
2. **stay** (code_stay,date_start,date_end),
3. **costumer_stay** (code_stay,code_costumer)

The script I created:

```
SELECT datediff(date_end,date_start) as dd,
       stay.code_stay,costumer_stay.code_costumer
FROM stay INNER JOIN costumer_stay 
          ON stay.code_stay=costumer_stay.code_stay;
```

but i cant get the one person with the longest stay,i get something like that:

```
id|code_stay|code_costumer|
---------------------------
25|xa21     |1001         |
8 |xb24     |1005         |
7 |xb30     |1003         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT datediff(date_end,date_start) as dd,
       stay.code_stay,costumer_stay.code_costumer
FROM stay 
INNER JOIN costumer_stay ON stay.code_stay = costumer_stay.code_stay
ORDER BY dd desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `order by` should be avoided for finding the top 1 result. This sorts the entire table then gives the one result.

Comment: @twentylemon: How else do you think a DB determines the biggest value of a table if not going through all values?

Comment: `order by` sorts the entire result table. O(n logn). Searching for a max value is just O(n)

Comment: I think this is a reasonable answer, especially because the question doesn't even mention performance.  The alternative answer still requires two passes through the table and cannot make use of an index, so the overall performance difference should not be that great.  If the OP cares about performance s/he should ask a separate question and be open to modifying the data structure.

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select code_stay from stay where datediff(date_end,date_start) = (
    select max(datediff(date_end,date_start)) from stay
)
```

should work

Comment: My bad. Didn't see the last one on a separate line.